# PHP Изображение в массив

Tags: php, изображения

Нужно считать изображение в массив цветовых значений пикселей или в массив байтов так, чтобы можно было вручную менять цветовые значения пикселей, а после преобразовать этот массив обратно в изображение.
На C# делал такое, а на PHP не могу найти((

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172115/how-can-i-get-the-pixel-value-of-image-in-php

Comment: Да, это помогло, спасибо.
Только что это за цветовая схема — "10779184, 9403447, 10518581, 10388300, 9601838, 11045174, 10585394, ..."?? Как разделить цвет на RGB или как с это схемой работать??

Comment: Ну сам пример перевода в rgb, можно глянуть в документации  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php

Comment: Там же в описании - "Если PHP скомпилирован с библиотекой GD 2.0 или выше и передается truecolor-изображение, функция возвращает целочисленное RGB значение для пиксела. Для выделения отдельных компонентов красного, зеленого или синего каналов используйте битовый сдвиг и маскирование:"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оформлю комментарий в качестве ответа:
Для получения индекса цвета используется функция [imagecolorat](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorat.php)

Что бы получить значения по всем пикселям изображения, необходимо обойти их все, получив ширину и высоту изображения:

```
$width = imagesx($resource);
$height = imagesy($resource);

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
        $color = imagecolorat($resource, $x, $y);
    }
}
```

Что бы из индекса получить отдельные значения rgba используем побитовое смещение:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
```

Что бы получить данные значения в массиве, можно использовать функцию [imagecolorsforindex](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorsforindex.php)

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);

$colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);

var_dump($colors);
```

Источники:

[ответ на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172115/how-can-i-get-the-pixel-value-of-image-in-php)

[документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorat.php)